# Need help sending email in PHP using Gmail SMTP

Tags: php, smtp, gmail

So I'm trying to follow the instructions here

http://www.9lessons.info/2011/07/send-mail-using-smtp-and-php.html

to use PHP to send out an email using my gmail account. But when I try to send a test email I get in the web browser this message: Error: could not connect to the host "smtp.gmail.com"

Here is are my two files (with my personal data edited)

Thanks for any help

```
<?php
print "1";
require("smtp.php");
require("sasl.php"); //SASL authentication
$from="support@yourwebsite.com"; 
$smtp=new smtp_class;
$smtp->host_name="smtp.gmail.com"; // Or IP address
$smtp->host_port=465;
$smtp->ssl=0;
$smtp->start_tls=1;
$smtp->localhost="localhost";
$smtp->direct_delivery=0;
$smtp->timeout=10;
$smtp->data_timeout=0;
$smtp->debug=1;
$smtp->html_debug=1;
$smtp->pop3_auth_host="";
$smtp->user="john@gmail.com"; // SMTP Username
$smtp->realm="";
$smtp->password="House22"; // SMTP Password
$smtp->workstation="";
$smtp->authentication_mechanism="";
print "3";
if($smtp->SendMessage(
$from,
array(
$to
),
array(
"From: $from",
"To: $to",
"Subject: $subject",
"Date: ".strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
),
"$message"))
{
print "Message sent to $to OK."; 
}
else
print "Cound not seend the message to $to.\nError: ".$smtp->error;
print "4";
?>

==============================

<?php
$to="ralph@website.com";
$fn="First Name";
$ln="Last Name";
$name=$fn.' '.$ln;
$from="test@grove.net";
$subject = "Welcome to Website";
$message = "Dear $name, 
Your Welcome Message.
Thanks
www.website.com
";
include('smtpwork.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per `Gmail` policy, You cannot use `plain password (house22)`, you have to use `encrypted password(Gh45515HGGujKkkHk5554)`, for that you need two way authentication should be enable on your gmail account. and after that, create Application Specific Password and then use that password for your SMTP, I hope that will work for you. here is the [link1](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) [Link2](http://www.shoutmeloud.com/how-to-generate-google-app-specific-password-2-step-verification.html)